# Modifying string literals or char arrays with pointer arithmetic

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, string-literals

I understand `char* pString` is read only, therefor `pString[0]='A'` will give a Segmentation fault, but why does `pString2[0]='A'` work in below code:

```
    char* pString  = "abcdefg";
    char tmpStr[80];
    strcpy(tmpStr, pString);
    char* pString2  = tmpStr;

    //pString[0] = 'A'; // gives segmentation error since string literal is read-only.
    pString2[0] = 'A'; // why this one works?
```

Comment: `pString2` is pointing to the first element of the (non-constant) array `tmpStr`. You can modify  the contents of `tmpStr` as much as you'd like, using the array directly or through a pointer like `pString2`.

Answer (score 2):

`pString2` is not pointing to a string literal.  It's pointing to the first element of a `char` array, and that array is not `const`, so writing to it is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration

```
char* pString  = "abcdefg";
```

the string literal is the record `"abcdefg"` not the declared pointer.

The string literal in C has the type `char[8]`. Though in the type there is absent the qualifier `const` nevertheless you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

In C++ opposite to C string literals have types of constant character arrays.

As for the declared pointer then it points to the first element of the string literal.

In this code snippet

```
char tmpStr[80];
strcpy(tmpStr, pString);
```

there is declared character array `tmpStr`. You may change the array.

In this statement

```
strcpy(tmpStr, pString);
```

elements of the string literal are copied in the character array.

And in the declaration below the declared pointer point to the first element of the array.

```
char* pString2  = tmpStr;

pString2[0] = 'A';
```

So you may change the array. You could use even the pointer `pString` instead of pString2 like

```
pString  = tmpStr;

pString[0] = 'A';
```

Pay attention to that you may initialize a character array with a string literal. So you could write for example

```
char tmpStr[] = "abcdefg";
*tmpStr = 'A';
```

or

```
tmpStr[0] = 'A';
```